# Authorization of commands in Axon

Tags: event-sourcing, axon

Up until now I have been handling authorization in the CommandHandlers.

An example is I have an aggregate "Team" containing a list of managers (AggregateIdentifier from a User). All command handlers in the Team aggregate then verify the user executing the command is manager of the team.
The userId is injected as metadata in a CommandHandlerInterceptor based on the SecurityContext.

My main concern is, when I use sagas, it becomes an additional overhead to maintain the user context across the commands issued against different aggregates. Aside from that, the manager association can expire in the period the saga is running and subsequent failing commands, leading to an incomplete state which also needs to be handled with some rollback functionality.

Is it better to do the authorization in my controller layer to avoid the additional overhead or should I see it more as good practice to let my CommandHandlers decide whether the command is valid for the aggregate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authorization to perform certain operations/commands is something which I'd argue isn't domain specific logic. Instead, it is more a form of cross cutting concern which you need throughout your application. Thus, placing it *in* the `@CommandHandler` annotated method is not the ideal place in my head. However, placing it close by makes a lot of sense.

You have pointed out you are already using a `CommandHandlerInterceptor` to populate the Spring `SecurityContext`, thus I am assuming you are using a `CommandDispatchInterceptor` to populate the command's `MetaData` with information when you send a command out. This is a great use of the interceptor logic indeed, so I'd keep that in place. This however set's the information, it doesn't validate it.

To that end, you could build your own [Handler Enhancer](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/handler-enhancers), which validates security metadata on a command. You could even build a dedicated annotation you'd add next to the `@CommandHandler` annotation, which describes the required roles. That way, the method still portrays what roles you need for the given command, but the actual validation can be done in this Handler Enhancer for you.

Now, let's circle back to your question:

> Is it better to do the authorization in my controller layer to avoid the additional overhead or should I see it more as good practice to let my CommandHandlers decide whether the command is valid for the aggregate?

I think it's fine to do it in the aggregate, potentially making it cleaner through use of a Handler Enhancer. When it comes to your concern in the Saga, well, I think you should see that separate. The Saga handles events, **facts** that something has happened. Ignoring that fact because somebody whom initiated the operations which led to this fact doesn't have the rights doesn't resolve the point that it still has happened. Added, you are indeed not guaranteed on the timing of the Saga at all. Maybe your Saga deals with historical events, meaning it is completely out of scope.

If possible within your system, I would regard *any* command the Saga wants to publish as being sent by a "system user". The Saga is not something your users (which have specific roles) will directly influence; it is all indirect. The Saga is internal to your system, hence it is the system describing the intent to perform an operation.

That's my two cents to the situation, hope this helps you out @Vincent!

Comment: Thank you, this really helped to have a second opinion.

I updated my CommandHandlerInterceptor to checking whether `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` is not null. If so, it will extract the user id and roles from the security context and set a metadata field "internal" to FALSE. If it is null, then I assume it is an internal service call and simply set a metadata field "internal" to TRUE. 

[Example](https://pastebin.com/EdtmHNy2)

I added a HandlerEnhancer where in the `WrappedMessageHandlingMember` the `canHandle`method is then checking this "internal" flag.

Comment: That's great to hear @Vincent! Happy to have been of help :-)

Comment: A follow-up question. I have it running by doing simple validation that the user have proper roles from the security context, but I have another scenario where I wish to extract my "Team" aggregate using the Repository from within the HandlerDefinition.
To solve that, I was thinking to autowire the repository in but it just seems clunky and I'm unable to find a good way besides having it as a parameter to my constructor of my extension of "WrappedMessageHandlingMember" in order to use it in the "canHandle" method

Comment: Is this `Team` Aggregate the _actual_ Aggregate the command is going to? Or, is this a different Aggregate you need to validate state through?

Comment: I can see that I described my follow-up question a bit bad, sorry for that :) 
I have a `Team` Aggregate where the command is going to. I also have an `Event` aggregate. Both the `Team` and `Event` aggregate contain a `List<ProfileId> managers`; If the user is present in either list of managers, they are permitted to execute the command. 

They are "related" to each other based on the `TeamId` aggregate identifier is a composite of a UUID and an EventId (aggregate identifier for `Event`)

The goal is to get the `Team` aggregate and `Event` aggregate and check the managers list for both.

Comment: Addition:
I have attempted annotating the implemented `HandlerEnhancerDefinition` with `@Component` and using both constructor based injection and setter based injection but in both cases, they are injected but the `wrapHandler` method is never invoked when I do that. If instead I don't `@Autowire` anything, the `wrapHandler` is correctly invoked. 

My idea is to add the injected beans as parameters to the constructor of my `WrappedMessageHandlingMember`.

Comment: Aaah, so you need contents of the Aggregate to form the security decision with, correct? Might be helpful to have a look at the `@CommandHandlerInterceptor` annotation you can use to annotate methods in the Aggregate itself to intercept the message. It is essentially similar to a `MessageHandlerInterceptor`, but with the added benefit of knowing the state of the Aggregate: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/messaging-concepts/message-intercepting#command-handler-interceptors